# How can I specify a list of comma delimited integers and have batch script loop for each integer?

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a batch script where I use "set /p =".  Once the variable is entered, the script performs 3 robocopy commands, using the  above.  After the 3 robocopy commands finish, I use another "set /p again=" to ask if the user needs to run this again.  Sometimes this script needs to run against 10-15 integers.

Is there a way to give a list of integers, comma delimited or otherwise, and have the script loop back for each subsequent integer?

`@echo off
:again
echo This script will download incident data in 2 steps.
echo Step 1 will attempt to download any previously archived data from your home drive.
echo Step 2 will attempt to download any files from the Live Incident folder.
set /p incident=Please enter the Incident Number:
robocopy "\\server1\share\%incident%" "C:\local-path\%incident%" *.* /ETA /MOV /E /R:1 /W:1 /MT:3
robocopy "\\server2\share\%incident%" "C:\local-path\%incident%" *.* /ETA /E /R:1 /W:1 /MT:2
robocopy "\\server3\share\%incident%" "C:\local-path\%incident%" *.* /ETA /E /R:1 /W:1 /MT:2
set /p again=Do you have another Incident you would like to try?
if /i "%again:~,1%" EQU "Y" goto again
if /i "%again:~,1%" EQU "N" exit /b`

Comment: Yes. If you [edit] your question and include your current script and the input file you want to use we might be able to help.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /F "tokens=*  delims=," %%a in (intergers.csv) Do (
set incident=%%a
echo !incident!
...add your script here without /p...

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
:again
echo This script will download incident data in 2 steps.
echo Step 1 will attempt to download any previously archived data from your home drive.
echo Step 2 will attempt to download any files from the Live Incident folder.

set /p "incidents=Please enter the Incident Numbers separated by a comma:"

For %%I in (%Incidents%) Do Call :Process %%I
CHOICE /C YN /M "Do you have another Incident you would like to try?"
If %ErrorLevel% Equ 1 Goto :again
Goto :Eof

:Process %1
:: you might do a range check on the Incident no. %1
Echo Processing Incedent # %1
:: while testing 
goto :Eof
robocopy "\\server1\share\%1" "C:\local-path\%casenum%" *.* /ETA /MOV /E /R:1 /W:1 /MT:3
robocopy "\\server2\share\%1" "C:\local-path\%casenum%" *.* /ETA      /E /R:1 /W:1 /MT:2
robocopy "\\server3\share\%1" "C:\local-path\%casenum%" *.* /ETA      /E /R:1 /W:1 /MT:2
Goto :Eof
```

If the output seems ok remove the `goto :eof` following `:: while testing`

Comment: It properly listed the incident numbers, but the robocopy paths all contained the comma separated list, as opposed to running multiple times for each incident number individually.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, March 24, 2017 18:43:59
   Source : \\server1\share\11111,22222,33333,44444,55555\
     Dest : C:\local-path\11111,22222,33333,44444,55555\

Comment: Did you change the `%incident%` in the robocopy command to `%1` ? I also don't know where the var `%casenum%` stem from.

Comment: %casenum% was supposed to be %incident%, I corrected it above.

Comment: In the called subroutine they have all to be changed to the passed first (and only) arg `%1` to work properly.